# How do I enable multitouch on cocos2d v3?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, controls, game-physics

I've been trying for ages to get this to work. I've searched all of the web, and can find only errors.

Here is my code for my initialize function in my HelloWorldScene.m

```
- (id)init
{
    // Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);

    // Enable touch handling on scene node

    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    self.exclusiveTouch = NO;
    self.claimsUserInteraction = NO;
    // Create a colored background (Dark Grey)
    CCNodeColor *background = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:0.2f green:0.2f blue:0.2f alpha:1.0f]];
    [self addChild:background];

    //Physics rules -- (Must go under [self addChild:background])
    _physicsWorld = [CCPhysicsNode node];
    //Sets the gravity of the world.
    _physicsWorld.gravity = ccp(0,0);
    _physicsWorld.debugDraw = YES;
    _physicsWorld.collisionDelegate = self;
    [self addChild:_physicsWorld];
    //End Physics Rules

    // Add a sprite
    _player = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"ship.png"];
    [_player setScaleX: .2f];
    [_player setScaleY: .2f];
    _player.position = ccp(110, self.contentSize.height / 2);
    _player.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, _player.contentSize} cornerRadius:1]; // 1
    _player.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"playerGroup"; // 2
    _player.physicsBody.collisionType = @"playerRect";
    [_physicsWorld addChild:_player];

    playerDirection = @"none";




    // Create a back button
    CCButton *backButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"[ Menu ]" fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:18.0f];
    backButton.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    backButton.position = ccp(0.85f, 0.95f); // Top Right of screen
    [backButton setTarget:self selector:@selector(onBackClicked:)];
    [self addChild:backButton];

    // done
    return self;
}
```

Here is my code for the actual multitouch

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];

    CGPoint targetPosition = ccp(self.contentSize.width, _player.position.y);

    if(touchLocation.x <= 350 && touchLocation.y >= 150){

    playerDirection = @"up";

    }

    if(touchLocation.x <= 350 && touchLocation.y <= 150){

    playerDirection = @"down";

    }

    bulletsOnScreen++;


    if(touchLocation.x >= 351){

   CCSprite *projectile = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"black.jpg"];
   [projectile setScaleX:.03f];
   [projectile setScaleY:.03f];
   projectile.position = _player.position;
   [self addChild:projectile ];

    CCActionMoveTo *actionMove   = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5f position:targetPosition];
    CCActionRemove *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];
    [projectile runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[actionMove,actionRemove]]];
}
```

I just want to be able to move and fire at the same time? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

currently using touchBegan but try -

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

instead of

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Answer (score 0):

After performing changes in:

```
AppController.mm.[eaglView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

We can start coding for `multitouch`.